# Conditions in which the series S have real zeros?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request

Let us consider the following series with respect to $x\in \mathbb R$:

$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (-1)^na_{n}(x)$$

where $a_{n}(x)\in \mathbb R$ is a positive real sequence.

**My question** is: I am looking to the results in the current literature about this fact: Conditions in which the series S have real zeros?, i.e., there exists some $x$ such that $S(x)=0$.

Comment: $S$ is (if it converges) a real number. What is a zero of $S$?

Comment: @martini: question edited.

Comment: If $a_n(x)$ is arbitrary, I don't see the point in putting a $(-1)^n$ factor.

Comment: @ajotatxe: did you mean that the term must be positive or negative.

Comment: If $S(x_0)=0$ then it means $a_1(x_0)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n a_n(x_0)$ . That's the condition because there are no other criterias. --- E.g.: $\displaystyle a_1(x):=\frac{x}{6}$ and $\displaystyle a_{n\geq 2}(x):=\frac{x^n}{2^n}$ with $x>0$ . It follows $S(1)=0$ .

Comment: @user90369: This method can be also applied too for $x$ being complexe.